# grid view of photos in wp-admin doesnot load, why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed plugin called force regenerate image but it didn't worked. photos are shown in list views but need to force regenerate the images many times. Its running fine in my localhost but in server its not loading how can i make it work fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze the log files on your server. It should contain clues on why it's not working. The location of your log files depends on your host. Contact your host if you have no idea where to find the log files.